# Choke at feed point of delta loop with Q match

Tags: antenna, loop-antenna, choke-balun

I am working on putting together a 40 meter delta loop using a 1/4 wavelength of RG-6 as the matching section.  However I'm unsure of where to create my feedpoint choke.

Do I coil up the RG6 right at the feedpoint of the antenna itself?  Or do I coil up the 50 ohm RG8x at the point where it feeds into the 75 ohm matching section?

EDIT: My choke consists of 8 turns of coax through a mix 31 big clamp on bead.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The choke should go at the transition between unbalanced and balanced, **which is where the RG-6 meets the ends of the loop wire.**

You talk of coiling coax: I suggest you coil it around a ferrite core and not just air. The trouble with air-core "chokes" is they have no resistance, only reactance, in common-mode. Depending on what the common-mode impedance is in the rest of the antenna system, adding this reactance might actually tune the common-mode to resonance, making things *worse*. A good choke has a substantially resistive impedance: this is guaranteed to raise the overall common-mode impedance in all cases. See [additional explanation by G3TXQ](http://www.karinya.net/g3txq/chokes/#inductive_chokes).

Comment: I presume that you mean that Paul should use a ferrite-core balun, rather than actually wrapping coax around a piece of ferrite.  The minimum bend radius of many varieties of coax would require quite a big piece of ferrite ;)

Comment: Comment moved to answer.

Comment: @MikeWaters I was thinking of the 4 inch (10 cm) minimum bend radius of LMR-400, but then I remembered [this discussion](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/10244/what-are-the-implications-of-pulling-lmr400-through-emt-conduit-with-several-90), which concluded that the specification for "bend radius: repeated" of 1 inch (2.5 cm) can be used for a one-time installation.

Comment: @rclocher3 Also, the coax doesn't need to be pulled tight around the core.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the 1 inch (2.5 cm) specification for "bend radius: installation".  The specification for "bend radius: repeated" is 4 inches (10 cm).

Comment: Edited my post to describe my choke solution.

Answer (score 4):

**Forget about air-core chokes**. G3TXQ's page that Phil links to in his excellent answer here shows just how much superior ferrite chokes are than air core choke baluns.

Please visit k9yc.com and download [rfi-ham.pdf](http://k9yc.com/RFI-Ham.pdf). Jim Brown there on page 36 recommends a choke balun made by wrapping 8 turns of the coax *at the antenna feedpoint* through four stacked 2.4" diameter #31 ferrite cores. They cost about $7 from http://www.mouser.com. And don't wrap the RG-6 too tight! That PDF tells how to properly wrap it.

Below is a similar choke balun that I made, at the base of [my 160m inverted-L](http://www.w0btu.com/160_meters.html#inv-l_antenna). Those are the exact Fair-rite #31 cores I mentioned above, with RG-6 coax. You don't need to make the loops as big as I did.

[image: W0BTU 160m choke balun]

(For 1.8 MHz, it really should have had more turns and cores, but it worked very well nonetheless.) I used this antenna on 160 through 20 meters, with great results.

Comment: I added my choke to the original post. Will that suffice?

Comment: @Paul Very good! I edited your post and changed your link to show the actual photo there.

Comment: @Paul Ok, you're using RG8-X and RG-6. Which is the light-colored coax? And which type is the dark colored coax? *Most importantly, where is the antenna connected in this photo*? Please go back and read Phil's answer here. :-)

Comment: That came from my old antenna. It is just an example of how I plan on making the choke. It sounds like I should do it with the RG-6 at the feedpoint of the delta loop.

Comment: @Paul Understood! You are correct.